# I cannot get the x-axis on my graph to format correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, dateformatter

I am trying to generate a live graph that shows my data as it is being read.
I want the X axis to display time in the format of

HH:MM

I found how to do

```
xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time 
import matplotlib
import threading
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import queue
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as mdate
from matplotlib import style

root = Tk()

graphXData = queue.Queue()
graphYData = queue.Queue()

def animate(objData):
    graph.clear()
    graph.plot(list(graphXData.queue), list(graphYData.queue))

graphFigure = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
graph = graphFigure.add_subplot(111)
graph.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
graph.xaxis_date()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graphFigure, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

for cnt in range (600):
    graphXData.put(matplotlib.dates.epoch2num(time.time()-(600-cnt)))
    graphYData.put(0)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(graphFigure,animate,interval=1000)
```

That gives me a full queue of the last 600 seconds as 0. And i'm putting in new data points in as

```
graphXData.put(matplotlib.dates.epoch2num(time.time()))
```

What I get is 0.0XX Where XX is some integer that I don't understand.

EDIT: As requested I made it into a working verified example and the result i get is

[image]

Comment: I don't think one can find out what you are doing and why that fails without a [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The code now gives a working example of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the formatter to the axes, but call `ax.clear()` afterwards. This clears the axes and removes the formatter. So from the first animation step on, it'll have the default formatter, which shows numbers.

A useful solution is to not clear the axes at all such that it'll keep its formatter.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time 
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import queue
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as mdate


root = Tk()

graphXData = queue.Queue()
graphYData = queue.Queue()

def animate(objData):
    line.set_data(list(graphXData.queue), list(graphYData.queue))
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis_date()
line, = ax.plot([],[])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

for cnt in range (600):
    graphXData.put(matplotlib.dates.epoch2num(time.time()-(600-cnt)))
    graphYData.put(0)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=1000)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One Thing That I will Add is that the Graph Continues To plot the previous points before the clear. This can cause a processor problem if your running off of a pi. So I added graph.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
graph.xaxis_date() between clear and plot in the animate function to keep the graph to the specific number of points